# How does the Identity theorem apply here?

Tags: complex-analysis

I need a hint for the following exercise: Prove that there exists no $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ that is holomorphic and such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n=2,3,\dots$

Normally I'd try to apply the Identity theorem, but the exponential is messing things up for me; I can't find a nice function. Also, I tried composing f with some known holomorphic functions, but no result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose there is such an $f.$ Then $f(0)=0$ but $f\not \equiv 0.$ Therefore $f(z) = z^mg(z)$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$ and holomorphic $g$ in $\mathbb D $ with $g(0)\ne 0.$ This implies $f(1/n)$ is on the order of $(1/n)^m$ as $n\to \infty.$ Is that possible?

Comment: I suppose $g(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(\frac{1}{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^m}{2^n}=0$ is the contradiction;Thank you, this is a very nice and simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

By analyticity,

$$(*)\quad  f^{(m)}(0) = m!  \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{ f(z) - \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} f^{(k)}(0) \frac{z^k}{k!}}{z^m}.$$

Now use induction to show that $f^{(m)}(0)=0$ for all $m$.

Base: $f(0)=0$.

Induction: $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,\dots, m-1$. Then by  $(*)$, 
$$f^{(m)}(0)= m! \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(z)}{z^m}= m! \lim_{n\to\infty} f(1/n)n^m=m!\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{-n} n^m=0.$$

Comment: Αnother nice answer. Since f is analytic, it cant have roots of infinite order, hence the contradiction. Thank you very much.